# Cannot bind dropdownlist to my linq queries

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datasource, html-select, linqdatasource

I am dragging in dropdownlist controls to my aspx page.  When I write any query in the asppx.vb page and try to bind it to my ddl the ddl remains unbound.  I have tried several different ways of doing it and none are working.  Even if I just create a blank page with a ddl and the most simple query it still won't bind.  I have tried clicking on the ddl and binding to a linq datasource that way and they will bind but I can't use that method as it is unsuitable.  I need to populate a ddl from a table called `Buildings` and then, based on the selection from that ddl, populate another one from a table called `Rooms`.

```
Protected Sub ddlBuilding_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlBuilding.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim db As New OrionDataClassesDataContext

    ddlBuilding.DataSource = (From build In db.Buildings
                            Select {build.Building_code, build.Building_name}).ToList()

    ddlBuilding.DataTextField = "Building_name"
    ddlBuilding.DataValueField = "Building_code"
    ddlBuilding.DataBind()
End Sub
```

This is one method I have tried.   Another method I tried is:

```
 Protected Sub ddlBuilding_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlBuilding.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim db As New OrionDataClassesDataContext

    Dim building = (From build In db.Buildings
                    Select {build.Building_code, build.Building_name}).ToList()

    ddlBuilding.DataSource = building
    ddlBuilding.DataTextField = "Building_name"
    ddlBuilding.DataValueField = "Building_code"
    ddlBuilding.DataBind()
End Sub
```

At this stage I don't think the query is the problem.  There is something that is stopping the `.databind` and `.datasource` functions from having any effect.  I have tried this with several ddls.  If anyone has any ideas please let me know.  Desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. I managed to just add LinqDataSources to the tables and select a Where clause to relate the two tables. I didn't think that would be possible for this issue but I was wrong